# Magento Ajax Add To Cart Button Error

Tags: error, ajax

I have recently set up a new magento store. Everything seems to be working apart from the most important thing, the `add to cart button`. It's odd because the smaller green add to cart buttons on the home page 
`www.creations-online.co.uk` work fine. However the larger orange add to car button on the individual product pages says error when pressed?!

I have tried starting again by re installing magento but it hasn't made any difference...

I can see an error message when I inspect with Google chrome either:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.creations-online.co.uk/index.php/creations/ajax/index/add/uenc/a…lvbmVyLTUwMG1sLmh0bWw_X19fU0lEPVU,/product/3368/form_key/dxLgYvodbd0VPQzZ/
```

Or

```
POST 

http://www.creations-online.co.uk/index.php/creations/ajax/index/add/uenc/a…lvbmVyLTUwMG1sLmh0bWw_X19fU0lEPVU,/product/3368/form_key/dxLgYvodbd0VPQzZ/ 404 (Not Found)
```

I can't figure this out!

Thanks for reading, any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is from the button that works:

POST

http://www.creations-online.co.uk/index.php/creations/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5jcmVhdGlvbnMtb25saW5lLmNvLnVrLw,,/product/3368/form_key/dxLgYvodbd0VPQzZ/

Comment: Looks like the module `creations` does not exist or does not have a route declared, or the `ajax` controller in the module is missing or the `index` action inside the `ajax` controller.

Comment: How can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The url looks wrong:

```
http://www.creations-online.co.uk/index.php/creations/ajax/index/add/
```

Normally the url has this structure:

```
<protocol>://<baseurl>/<package>/<controller>/<action>/<param1>/<value1>/<param2>/<value2>
```

But your url has four parts, so either the package's name is `creations_ajax` or the controller is `Ajax/IndexController.php` or the action is `indexAddAction`? Whatever it is, happy fixing.

Comment: I still can't figure this out?!

Comment: What is the name of the package you want to call? The name of the controller and the name of the action?

Comment: i've added the command from the button that works, i have just added it to me original question as it wouldn't fit in this box!

Comment: I can see the difference i need to change the /ajax/index/ part with /checkout/cart/ But where do I do this in magento?

Comment: Try this: `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);`

Comment: Apologies Fabian, thank you so much for all your help! Where is this located?

Comment: This method returns a link, this link needs to be on the button. So wherever you add your button, this methods needs to be called.